# Is it possible to get the name taskAffinity which the Activity belongs to during runtime?

Tags: android

I was wondering, is it possible to get the name of `taskAffinity` which the `Activity` belongs to, during runtime?

I search through but unable to find a way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

> The affinity of an activity is defined by the taskAffinity attribute.
> The affinity of a task is determined by reading the affinity of its
> root activity. Therefore, by definition, a root activity is always in
> a task with the same affinity.

So to get the taskAffinity of an activity, we will get the taskAffinity of the root activity (the activity at the bottom of the stack).

Here is the solution:

*ActivityUtils.java*

```
public static String getTaskAffinity(Activity activity) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> appTaskList = am.getAppTasks();

    int taskId;
    for (ActivityManager.AppTask appTask : appTaskList) {
        ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo taskInfo = appTask.getTaskInfo();

        // Get the id of the task
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            taskId = taskInfo.id;
        } else {
            taskId = taskInfo.taskId;
        }

        // Detect the task that the activity is belonged to
        if (activity.getTaskId() == taskId) {
            ComponentName rootActivity = taskInfo.baseActivity;
            try {
                PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
                ActivityInfo ai = pm.getActivityInfo(rootActivity, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                return ai.taskAffinity;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using from Activity:

```
String taskAffinity = ActivityUtils.getTaskAffinity(this);
```

Using from Fragment

```
String taskAffinity = ActivityUtils.getTaskAffinity(requireActivity());
```