# Activity which launched from sharing intent filter doesn't obey android:taskAffinity rule during onNewIntent

Tags: android

Currently, my app does accept share content from external app.

In order to avoid sharing action from interference with current running main app, I mention `android:taskAffinity` explicitly.

I also try best effort to ensure there is only one and only one `com.xxx.MyActivity` in task `com.xxx.share` by using

1. `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
2. `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.xxx.MyActivity"
    android:taskAffinity="com.xxx.share"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When MyActivity is being created for the first time (`onCreate` being called), I am able to verify it is inside task named "com.xxx.share".

However, if the MyActivity is being "reused" (`onNewIntent` being called), it is **NO** longer inside task name "com.xxx.share".

I am using the following way, to get the current task name - [Is it possible to get the name taskAffinity which the Activity belongs to during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001967/is-it-possible-to-get-the-name-taskaffinity-which-the-activity-belongs-to-during)

I was wondering, why it is so? How can I force the Activity (invoked via sharing intent filter) always

- Launch in specified task name
- Be the one and only one Activity in the task

---

p/s
If the `Activity` is launching within my home widget, or drop down notification, I can easily achieve such by using

```
<activity android:name="com.xxx.widget.MyActivity"
    android:taskAffinity="com.xxx.launcher"
    
public static int getClearEverythingFlagsForLauncher() {
    return Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK;
}
    
final android.content.Intent openIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
openIntent.addFlags(getClearEverythingFlagsForLauncher());
```

But now, launching Activity via sharing intent is pretty out of my control. I can no longer supply `getClearEverythingFlagsForLauncher()`.

Comment: "Could you give a scenario when "if the MyActivity is being "reused" happen? and what is the task name of the MainActivity when onNewItent called?

Comment: Share text to MyActivity, onCreate will be called. Then press HOME. Share another text to MyActivity. This time, onCreate will not be called. Instead, onNewIntent will be called. You will notice during second time, it is not in the desired android:taskAffinity

Comment: So you used 2 separate apps to share text?

Comment: No. You can just use a web browser, share 2 different URLs

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue on 3 browsers, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, and this behavior is only happening on Chrome. I guess Chrome force your activity to launch on their own task somehow regardless launchMode and taskAffinity. In this case, you can create a dispatcher activity to forward data from another apps to your app.